# htmlspecialchars() - How and when to use and avoid multiple use

Tags: php, mysql, html, validation, forms

I'm building a PHP intranet for my boss. A simple customer, order, quote system. It will be denied access from the Internet and only used by 3 people. I'm not so concerned with security as I am with validation. Javascript is disables on all machines.

The problem I have is this:

1. Employee enters valid data into a form containing any of the following `:;[]"'` etc.
2. Form $_POSTS this data to a validationAndProcessing.php page, and determines whether the employee entered data or not in to the fields. If they didn't they are redirected back to the data input page and the field they missed out is highlighted in red.
3. htmlspecialchars() is applied to all data being re-populated to the form from what they entered earlier.
4. Form is then resubmitted to validationAndProcessing.php page, if successful data is entered into the database and employee is taken to display data page.

My question is this:

If an employee repeatedly enters no data in step 1, they will keep moving between step 1 and 4 each time having htmlspecialchars() applied to the data.

```
So that:- &
becomes:- &amp;
becomes:- &amp;amp;
becomes:- &amp;amp;amp;
```

etc..

How can I stop htmlspecialchars() being applied multiple times to data that is already cleaned?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 5):

Check the [manual page on htmlspecialchars](http://de.php.net/htmlspecialchars):

> string htmlspecialchars  (  string $string  [,  int $quote_style = ENT_COMPAT  [,  string $charset  [,  **bool $double_encode = true**  ]]] )

the `$double_encode` option should be what you are looking for.

In a properly set up data flow, though, this *shouldn't* be a possibility at all, except if there is data incoming from the user or a 3rd party service that could or could not already contain HTML encoded characters. (Not that I haven't built a few improperly set up data flows in my career. But that's why I know why it's so important they're clean and well defined. :-)

Comment: `$double_encode` is a hack; it'll prevent anyone from using the literal string `&amp;` or similar to mean exactly that. Much better to fix the data flow. Only use `htmlspecialchars()` in the final HTML templating stage, never over input or database content, and you should be fine. Step 3 in the question seems highly suspicious.

Comment: @bobince step 3 it the only possible way according to standards :)

Comment: Of course you need `htmlspecialchars` *when outputting text into HTML*. However step 3 makes it sound like it is being blanket-applied to all content outside of the HTML-output step, which would certainly explain the double-escaping.

Comment: @bobince he doesn't output text into HTML. He fills form's input values. At least he should :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, that's exactly what I'm doing, which is why I'm using htmlspecialchars(), but finding myself in a bind. I'm sure I'm doing something that doesn't match standards but i dont know what

@bobince and @col. shrapnel, looks like i need to look at my data flow. Do you have any ideas on where I can find material on how to do this? I've looked about but I'm not sure.

Comment: @naescent I'm not sure I follow you: Won't the `htmlspecialchars()` ed text be interpreted as normal characters (i.e. `&amp;` will be turned into a visible `&`) by the browser when you insert the form information? I don't see how the flow you describe would end in character data being double-encoded.

Comment: @Pekka No. Typed values are not HTML-escaped by the browser before submission. All values are url-encoded for transfer but this is generally transparent to the server-side handler.

Comment: I really want to use this feature, but it's not available on the version of PHP I am running (5.1.6).

Answer (score 5):

You should only be using `htmlspecialchars` in the HTML output, never anywhere else.

```
<input name="var" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($var)?>">
```

If `$var` contained an ampersand, say, then in the HTML it would output the encoded value:

```
<input name="var" value="this&amp;that">
```

However, the user would only see `this&that` in their input field, and upon submission, `$_GET['var']` will be `this&that`, not the encoded version.

On the PHP side of things the only thing you may want to do is remove slashes if magic quotes are on:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    $var = stripslashes($_POST['var']);
else
    $var = $_POST['var'];
```

From there you should store the raw data in the database, not HTML-encoded versions. To avoid SQL injection, use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you're using normal mysql functions, or use [PDO](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: What's the negative of using htmlspecialchars on things like user comments before storing them? Means you'll never forget on output?

Comment: @Silver89 it's best to store the true, canonical data in the database. It helps with using the data for other things, e.g. maybe you want to process the data later. Plus your idea doesn't really solve anything because now you could forget to encode on input, and then have varied encoding in your database.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat This is only possible if you're using UTF-8 to store the data. If you're stuck with ISO-8859-1 then you need to use the double_encode parameter on htmlentities or htmlspecialchars so it doesn't convert characters like &#283; to &amp;#283;

Comment: @Paul that's sort of the point of the answer: you should be using UTF-8 across the board so situations like that don't happen. You should never be "stuck" without it. Also it's possible if your database is not UTF-8 as long as your pages have the same encoding as the DB.

Answer (score -4):

```
So that:- &
becomes:- &amp;
becomes:- &amp;amp;
becomes:- &amp;amp;amp;
```

You are simply wrong. 
Just try it and see

```
<form>
<input name="a" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET["a"])?>">
<input type=submit>
</form>
```